# How to print an ArrayList of GRects (Java acm)

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Brick> tiles = new ArrayList<Brick>();
public void init(){

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
          tiles.add( new Brick(30,10,Color.red));
    }
myPrint(tiles);
}

private static void myPrint(ArrayList<Brick>tiles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(tiles.toString());
}
```

Above is me trying to add Brick object to an arraylist, but failing to print it.

Here is the Brick class:

```
public class Brick extends GCompound {
    public Brick(int width, int height, Color color) {

        GRect rect = new GRect(width, height);
        rect.setFilled(true);
        rect.setFillColor(color);       
    }
```

Nothing shows up when i run the code. I tried adding a toString method, but it didnt work either.
I also tried making a `ArrayList<GRect> tiles = new ArrayList<GRect>();`, but couldn't print that either.
My question is, how can i print an arrayList of rectangle objects?

**Edit:**

If i wasn't clear about my goal, here is a screenshot of something similar to what i'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

I made this using for loops, but i will be adding conditions under which rectangles will have to be deleted, so i figured an ArrayList would suit best.

Comment: You're creating a GRect object inside your Brick constructor but you're not assigning it to anything - it just disappears into thin air. Why? What is the purpose?

Comment: you are very far from your goal, you dont have a main method even. Also you are trying to drow something maybe, but thats absolutely wrong aproach, you are close to printing the object hashcode

Comment: Try `tiles.forEach(System.out::println);`  as the body of your myPrint method

Comment: @gen.Strash yeah i am trying to draw the bricks, but im getting the hashcodes.

Comment: Your edit actually has made it even less clear what you are asking for

Comment: @RobinTopper With for loops i am able to see the rectangles i add to my canvas, but i can't do the same with an arraylist, all i get is a blank screen. All i need basically is a bunch of rectangles on my screen.

Comment: Consider making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In your `Brick` constructor, you are creating the `GRect` object and not holding any reference for it.

So you need to keep reference for `GRect` reference as an instance variable for `Brick` and also override `toString()` as shown below:

```
public class Brick extends GCompound {

    private GRect rect;

    public Brick(int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.rect = new GRect(width, height);
        this.rect.setFilled(true);
        this.rect.setFillColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Brick{" +
                "Height=" + rect.getHeight() +
                "Width=" + rect.getWidth() +
                "Color=" + rect.getFillColor() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Also, your `myPrint()` method you are calling `tiles.toString()` inside a `for` loop which is unnecessary, so update `myPrint` method as shown below:

```
private static void myPrint(ArrayList<Brick> tiles) {
    System.out.println(tiles);//remove for loop and printing tiles calls toString()
}
```